# Cayley db user and password protection over HTTP connections

Tags: cayley

I am new to Cayley db. I am trying it for my applicaiton, and for my interest in graph db concepts.

I have not seen anything referring to a database user or a password for accessing to a database in Cayley documentation. Moreover, [drivers on npm to connect to Cayley](https://www.npmjs.com/search?q=cayley) from Nodejs does not mention anything other than host and port.

On what level db user accounts and password protection of databases achieved in using Cayley database? Is that achieved on the persistence layers that Cayley depends upon, leveldb, bolt, mongodb?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As there is no other answer for that I am answering my own question myself.

Since Cayley persists data in a supported by Cayley db (boltdb, levelled, mongoldb) the user accounts of the db is managed by one of those dbs and so inside their own user accounts system.

On a HTTP application case which is the most common case, the HTTP server reaches the Cayley db for input/output, so, the HTTP server application code manages the authorization and authentication in access to database resources by a custom mechanism. This end is free to choose from many.

The operating system (OS) that runs Cayley db can be configured in its own way (specific to OS) to control network access to Cayley db, separately. Most of the cases Cayley runs on the same machine as the companion HTTP server application so, OS can block the network access to the Cayley db. In other cases again OS can be configured to accept network access to Cayley db only from predetermined set of IPs and in predetermined protocol, which is HTTP in that case (one reaches a Cayley instance over HTTP).