# Connecting to Cayley serving over localhost

Tags: node.js, gremlin, cayley

I've followed the 'Getting Started' guide in Cayley's documentation and installed Cayley on my remote server:

> Getting Started: https://github.com/google/cayley

**Server OS**: CentOS 7.2.1511

I've added cayley to my $PATH:

`echo $PATH` :

> /usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/home/csse/cayley/src/github.com/google/cayley

Here is my config file at `/etc/cayley.cfg`

```
{
  "database": "leveldb",
  "db_options": {
    "cache_size_mb": 2,
    "write_buffer_mb": 20
  },
  "db_path": "~/cayley/src/github.com/google/cayley/data/testdata.nq",
  "listen_host": "127.0.0.1",
  "listen_port": "64210",
  "read_only": false,
  "replication_options": {
    "ignore_missing": false,
    "ignore_duplicate": false
  },
  "timeout": 30
}
```

I serve cayley over http by simply doing:

`cayley http`

and the terminal outputs:

> Cayley now listening on 127.0.0.1:64210

On my main machine (Mac OSX 10.10.5 Yosemite), I've used npm to install the `cayley` package and written a test:

##testconnection.js

```
var cayley = require('cayley');

var client = cayley("137.112.104.107");

var g = client.graph;

g.V().All(function(err, result) {
    if(err) {
        console.log('error');
   } else {
        console.log('result');
   }
});
```

However, it fails when I run it: `node testconnection.js`

> error: Error: Invalid URI "137.112.104.107/api/v1/query/gremlin"

I'd like to connect to Cayley and modify the database from my test. I've found a great powerpoint full of Cayley information:

https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/1tCbsYym1kXWWDcnRU9ymj6xP0Nvgq-Qhy9WDmqWcM-o/edit#slide=id.g3776708f1_0319

As well as pertinent Cayley docs:

- [Overview Doc](https://github.com/google/cayley/blob/master/docs/Overview.md)
- [Configuration Doc](https://github.com/google/cayley/blob/master/docs/Configuration.md)
- [HTTP API Doc](https://github.com/google/cayley/blob/master/docs/HTTP.md#apiv1write)

And a post on stackoverflow:

- [Cayley db user and password protection over HTTP connections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33324940/cayley-db-user-and-password-protection-over-http-connections/33833371#33833371)

But I'm struggling to come up with a way to connect Cayley (on my remote machine) with my local machine. I'd like to connect with npm if possible, but am open to other options. Where am I going wrong?

## Edit #1

I've appended the "http://" to my ip, so now it reads `http://137.112.104.107`. At that point, I solved another issue by performing

`cayley init --config=/etc/cayley.cfg`
as mentioned by the author [here](https://github.com/cayleygraph/cayley/issues/339#issuecomment-157718862)

I've also removed the `listen_post` and `listen_port` from my config file (each individually first, then both), yet have still have the same `socket hang up` error. Here's a printout of `client` from the test script:

```
Client {
    host: 'http://137.112.104.107',
    request:
        { [Function]
        get: [Function],
        head: [Function],
        post: [Function],
        put: [Function],
        patch: [Function],
        del: [Function],
        cookie: [Function],
        jar: [Function],
        defaults: [Function] },
    graph: Gremlin { client: [Circular], query: [Function] },
    g: Gremlin { client: [Circular], query: [Function] },
    write: [Function: bound ],
    delete: [Function: bound ],
    writeFile: [Function: bound ]
}
```

Comment: You forgot `http://` before the IP.

Comment: Added the http:// before the IP. New error -> error: Error: socket hang up

Comment: Your server is listening only on localhost, remove the `listen_port` line and the listener is on a specific port (64210).

Comment: I mean `listen_host`.

Comment: I made your changes and updated the question. Unfortunately no luck so far

Comment: The default port of cayley is always 64210, if you don't put any port in your client, it tries to reach port 80. `var client = cayley("http://137.112.104.107:64210");`

Answer (score 0):

Your Cayley server is listening on 127.0.0.1 / localhost and therefor not reachable from another machine. To be able to reach it from a virtual machine or another computer on your network it needs to bind to an interface that is reachable.

If you configure host: 0.0.0.0 and check what is your network IP (I assume: 137.112.104.107) and connect it, it should work or you need to open it or forward the port on your firewall (depending on your network).